# Set State form return value of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I want to set the state of `timeToCountdown` with the value of `allTimeInSeconds`.

Then I want to send that data as a prop to a component.

```
class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 

        this.state = {
            hours: "",
            minutes: "",
            seconds: "",
            timeToCountdown: ""   
        };

        this.grabHours = this.grabHours.bind(this);
        this.grabMinutes = this.grabMinutes.bind(this);
        this.grabSeconds = this.grabSeconds.bind(this);
        this.changeAllTimeInputsToSeconds = this.changeAllTimeInputsToSeconds.bind(this);
    }

   changeAllTimeInputsToSeconds(){
        var timerHours = Number((parseInt(this.hours.value, 10)*3600)) || 0
        var timerMinutes = Number((parseInt(this.minutes.value, 10)*60)) || 0
        var timerSeconds = Number(parseInt(this.seconds.value, 10)) || 0

        var allTimeInSeconds = timerHours + timerMinutes + timerSeconds;       

        this.setState({timeToCountDownValue: this.allTimeInSeconds});

        console.log(allTimeInSeconds);

        return allTimeInSeconds;
    }
```

Comment: And the question is?...

Comment: Question is not clear ? Please make it understandable

Comment: I want to update this.state.timeToCountdown with the value of allTimeInSeconds

Comment: the state of timeToCountdown is not updated with allTimeToSeconds.

Comment: I followed the instruction in the reply beneath and that is the result I'm telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th error is here:

```
var allTimeInSeconds = timerHours + timerMinutes + timerSeconds;       
this.setState({ timeToCountDownValue: this.allTimeInSeconds });
```

The variable `this.allTimeInSeconds` does not exits. I guess this would work:

```
const allTimeInSeconds = timerHours + timerMinutes + timerSeconds;       
this.setState({ timeToCountDownValue: allTimeInSeconds });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do it this way, if I understood the question correctly:

Assuming `timeToCountDown` is the value you want to send as property, you don't need to return the value in the function `changeAllTimeInputsToSeconds`. As you already doing, you can use `setState()` function to update the `state` value. Then it is being send to your component automatically.

`MyComponent` has to be replaced with your component, you want to send the property.

```
class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 

        this.state = {
            hours: "",
            minutes: "",
            seconds: "",
            timeToCountdown: 0,
        };

        this.grabHours = this.grabHours.bind(this);
        this.grabMinutes = this.grabMinutes.bind(this);
        this.grabSeconds = this.grabSeconds.bind(this);
        this.changeAllTimeInputsToSeconds();
    }

   changeAllTimeInputsToSeconds(){
        var timerHours = Number((parseInt(this.hours.value, 10)*3600)) || 0
        var timerMinutes = Number((parseInt(this.minutes.value, 10)*60)) || 0
        var timerSeconds = Number(parseInt(this.seconds.value, 10)) || 0
        var allTimeInSeconds = timerHours + timerMinutes + timerSeconds;       
        this.setState({timeToCountDown: allTimeInSeconds });
        console.log(allTimeInSeconds);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponent timeToCountdown={this.state.timeToCountdown} />
        )
    }
```

Comment: When I call the props in the child component it is not updated to the allTimeInSeconds variable. It still remains 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
get hours, minute and seconds value from the state

var timerHours = Number((parseInt(this.hours.value, 10)*3600)) || 0
        var timerMinutes = Number((parseInt(this.minutes.value, 10)*60)) || 0
        var timerSeconds = Number(parseInt(this.seconds.value, 10)) || 0

use this.state.hours in place of this.hours similar for other values
```

as of your current code, the value of the timeToCountdown  will also be zero even in the current component